# Insert multiple documents on duplicate update existing document with the new document?

Tags: mongodb

What is the correct method for inserting multiple documents, say `5,000` of them in one command, on duplicate unique index, updating existing documents with new documents on all fields?

For instance, out of the `5,000` documents, `1,792` of them are new with no duplicates by unique indexes so they are inserted, and `3,208` of them have duplicates in the collection by unique indexes which should be replaced into the existing ones by all values.

I tried `insertMany()` with the unordered option but it seems to skip duplicate documents.

And then `updateMany()` with `upsert:true` isn't for inserting multiple documents but only updating certain fields in a collection?

Is this possible at all?

========Example=========

For a business collection with unique index of field "name":

```
{"name":"Google", "address":"...", "employees":38571, "phone":12345}
{"name":"Microsoft", "address":"...", "employees":73859, "phone":54321}
{"name":"Apple", "address":"...", "employees":55177, "phone":88888}
{"name":"Meta", "address":"...", "employees":88901, "phone":77777}
```

Now we want to update the collection with these 4 documents:

```
{"name":"Apple", "address":"...", "employees":55177, "phone":22222}
{"name":"Dell", "address":"...", "employees":77889, "phone":11223}
{"name":"Google", "address":"...", "employees":33333, "phone":44444}
{"name":"IBM", "address":"...", "employees":77777, "phone":88888}
```

In MySQL, I could just do this in one query:

```
INSERT INTO business (name, address, employees, phone)
    VALUES
    ('Apple', '...', 55177, 22222),
    ('Dell', '...', 77889, 11223),
    ('Google', '...', 33333, 44444),
    ('IBM', '...', 77777, 88888)
    AS new
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    address = new.address
    employees = new.employees
    phone = new.phone
```

And the collection documents become:

```
{"name":"Google", "address":"...", "employees":33333, "phone":44444} # updated
{"name":"Microsoft", "address":"...", "employees":73859, "phone":54321} # no change
{"name":"Apple", "address":"...", "employees":55177, "phone":22222} # updated
{"name":"Meta", "address":"...", "employees":88901, "phone":77777} # no change
{"name":"Dell", "address":"...", "employees":77889, "phone":11223} # inserted
{"name":"IBM", "address":"...", "employees":77777, "phone":88888} # inserted
```

How do I do this in MongoDB?

Comment: You could be looking for [$setOnInsert](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) to distinguish insert and update case in the upsert. However, I would suggest, if possible, identify the duplicate cases and insert only the latest one to simplify things and improve performance.

Comment: But then distinguishing existing ones from new ones costs more queries. I have to go through 5000 documents one by one and check each one of them for existence by unique index, right? Then I could just check them one after another and if exist, update, if not, insert. Tha'ts very tedious and a performance nightmare? MySQL has bulk insert on duplicate update, why doesn't Mongodb?

Comment: It could be better if you can sample some documents to illustrate. From the figures you provided now, skipping the insertion/update of the 3208 duplicate documents looks like a strong boost. You can simply use one `$group` query to select the latest document per group for insert.

Comment: But we don't know beforehand which of the 5000 documents are new or not, so we have to go through them one by one, and update any of them if it exists, or insert it if it doesn't? That's the only way with Mongodb? I don't think `$group` is helpful here, is it? Nor is `$setOnInsert` since it updates multiple documents with just one value per field but not the values in each distinct document?

Comment: It seems like the current logic depends on the natural order of your documents. It is hard to have some conclusion if we can't get more context from some simple actual example. Can you include some illustration?

Comment: @ray Hi there, I've updated the question with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just need the `$merge`. Put the documents you need to go through into another collection(says toBeInserted). `$merge` toBeInserted into the existing collection.

```js
db.toBeInserted.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      // select the relevant fields
      _id: 0,
      name: 1,
      address: 1,
      employees: 1,
      phone: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "companies",
      "on": "name",
      "whenMatched": "merge",
      "whenNotMatched": "insert"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DHggKUbwN4K)

Comment: I'm quite new to Mongodb but Is this the best solution performance wise? I'd have to first create a temporary collection?

Comment: Iikely. As you said that we can't boost by skipping some documents, so `$merge` should be equivalent to your ON DUPLICATE UPDATE